# Make PHP database class generic by Generating dynamic variables

Tags: php, php-parse-error

Please look at the code, the array contains the table field names of the table

```
class User {
    public $db_fields = array('id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name');

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

}
```

The idea is to remove the public variables with a function so that it automatically creates public variable from the array which i can access ---

**Example**

I want to remove the

```
public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $first_name;
public $last_name;
```

section, and want this to be automatically generated by the `$db_fields` array.

So that I can access the objects by

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = "Ismail";
```

What I did was

```
extract($db_fields);
```

but it gives an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\advphp\dbclass\extractex.php on line 3

Comment: You really, *really* need to [review PHP's OOP documentation](http://php.net/language.oop5).  You seem to be making a bad assumption about how class members are accessed in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately your idea does not work
if you try to use `extract($db_fields);` it's a method it need to run from inside a method
something like a constructor or a function. `extract($db_fields);` it will extract the variables for you but they wont be public they will be local to that function for example if you try this

```
function __construct(){
    extract($db_fields);
    // the $id will be available in the constructor only
    // it will get disposed when this method finished executing
}
```

another approach is to use a property or setter and getter approach

```
<?php
class User {
    private $db_fields = array(
                        'id', 
                        'username', 
                        'password' => 'ismailPassword', 
                        'first_name',
                        'last_name'
      );

    function getValue($key){
       if (array_key_exists($key, $this->db_fields)){
            return $this->db_fields[$key];
       }
       return NULL;
    }

    function setValue($key, $value){
        $this->db_fields[$key] = $value;        
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->setValue('username', 'Ismail');
echo " Username: ";
echo $user->getValue('username');
echo "\n\n Password: ";
echo $user->getValue('password');
?>
```

you can test the codes here http://codepad.org/8MwBwdut

Answer (score 1):

You could remove `$db_fields` all together and depend on the columns returned by your SQL query like so:

```
class User
{
    private $_data;
    public function __construct($id = null) {
        //TODO: Load data into $this->_data for user of $id
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_data))
            return $this->_data[$name];

        return NULL;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->_data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function UpdateUser(){
        //TODO: update the database with any changes to the user data or do an insert for new user
    }
}
```

and then you can get/set properties dynamically without needing to first declare them like so:

```
$newUser = new User();
$newUser->username = "Ismail";
$newUser->UpdateUser();
```

Comment: I understood it, but can you tell me where is the database connection or in which table the data is going to be saved. I mean, can you describe the code?

Answer (score 0):

If your database result returns key value pairs you can do this:

```
$array = array();
while (($r = $result->fetch_array()) != false){
   $obj = new \stdClass();
   foreach($r as $key => $value){
       $obj->$key = $value;
   }
   $array[] = $obj;
}
```